# Wi-Fi networks not detected on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (rtl8723be)

Tags: network-adapter, ubuntu-14.04, wifi-configuration

I have an hp pavillion 15-ab030tx and I recently dual booted windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04LTS. No Wifi networks are being displayed, but if I host a hotspot from my phone it is visible and I am able to connect from my laptop. I am also able to connect to hidden networks if I am close to the router. On windows I am able to connect to any network and range and visibility arent any issues. I installed the drivers for realtek found on git hub (rtlwifi_new) with no success. My kernel verision is 3.16.0.45-generic and network adapter is rtl8723be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did toy try to create a new wifi network option?

Comment: I tried but it won't connect unless I'my really close to the source of the network

Comment: did you install drivers properly?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I looked at many different sources and I'm certain the drivers were installed properly

Answer (score 1):

I have the same wireless card and faced the same problem for a lot of time.
I also tried the lwfinger's new rtl_wifi drivers but the problem still persisted.

I've fixed the problem and made a bash file.

1. Clone this git repo https://github.com/roopansh/rtl8723be_wifi
2. Open a terminal and enter the following command

   ```
   bash rtl8723be.sh
   ```
3. It will ask for a password - just enter your password.
4. The problem should now be gone. Restart your PC if it's still unable to find WiFi hotspots in range more than five feet.